# Page Visibility API Testing

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, visibility

Is it possible to use PhantomJS to test a page's functionality/network traffic/etc. when it is loaded without being "visible" according to the [Page Visibility API](http://ie.microsoft.com/TEStdrive/Performance/PageVisibility/Default.html)? And then what happens as the page does become visible?

Essentially, the use case I'd like to hit is:

1. Page is loaded in the background, or pre-cached (i.e., `document.hidden=true`)
2. Test inspects page, makes assertions
3. Page becomes visible, or `document.hidden` is set to false
4. Test inspects page/network traffic/makes assertions

I'm wondering how regression testing of the page visibility stuff is currently done.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to test visibility functionality, because every page is always visible in PhantomJS 2 (PhantomJS 1.x doesn't support the Page Visibility API).

There is also no synthetic solution. The problem is that `document.hidden` is immutable and cannot be replaced. So even if you can trigger the "visibilitychange" event on the document, the listeners on the page still check the `document.hidden` property when the event is triggered.